# How to change alphabets entered by user

Tags: python

I want to replace the text entered by user like this:

- a being the first character I want to replace it with the last character z
- replace b with y
- replace c with x
- do this vise versa
- replace z with a.

If the user enters `abc` then I want to print `zyx`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Next time, please provide more information if possible so that people can present better solutions. For example, it helps to know that the input might be a sentence instead of a single word as the current post seems to suggest. (I posted an answer below, only to realize that sentences should also be considered.)

Answer (score 2):

This is merely a problem of mathematics.

Let index for 
a is 1, b is 2 and so on for z = 26, and you want a to be equivalent to z or 1 to be equivalent to 26 in terms of numbers, simply

a = 1 ==> z = 26

b = 2 ==> y = index of z - index of b + index of a = 26-2+1 = 25 = y

But when we implement this approach only difference lies in the index value or ascii value. 
Ascii value for a is 97 and for z it is 122.
So in the code given below,

```
user_input = input("input the string: ")
output = []
for i in user_input:
    output.append(chr(122-ord(i)+ 97))

print("Resulting string is: ", "".join(output))
```

I got the ascii value of each character using ord(), applied the logic, converted back the ascii value to character using chr(), appended each character to the list and finally printed the list elements using join().

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def reverse_alphabet(s):
  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  return ''.join([alphabet[-alphabet.index(c)-1] if c in alphabet else c for c in s])

print(reverse_alphabet("ab  xy"))  # Output  "zy ab"
```

**Explanation**

Letters in use

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Index of a particular letter in the alphabet

```
alphabet.index(c)
```

Reverse letter in alphabet corresponding to letter c

```
alphabet[-alphabet.index(c)-1]
```

Only reverse letter c if it is in the alphabet (i.e. other characters like spaces unchanged)

```
alphabet[-alphabet.index(c)-1] if c in alphabet else c  # note if conditon
```

Map all the letters in the string using list comprehension

```
[alphabet[-alphabet.index(c)-1] if c in alphabet else c for c in s]
```

Convert List to string

```
''.join(...)
```

Comment: It worked thank you, im still very new to python and programming in general

Comment: I see that it only allow me to input one word, but a sentence produces a value error

Comment: @GrantSolomons--thought it was single words.  Updated solutionnow handles sentences with multiple words.  Since you mention a-z I assume you only meant lower case letters.  Let me know if you need it for uppercase also.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach on top of @DarryIG's answer for OP's reference:

```py
def reverse(s):
    res = ''
    for char in s:
        res += chr(- ord(char) + 219)
    return res
```

Let me provide you with a quick rundown of the code. First, the `ord` function converts a character into a number with specific ordering. For example,

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('b')
98
>>> ord('z')
122
```

You can easily see that the numbers are literally "ordered" in a convenient fashion. This means that we can use this to our advantage to obtain the reverse of the input string.

The `chr` function does the exact opposite of `ord`: it converts an ordering back into a character string. For example,

```
>>> chr(97)
'a'
```

The `reverse` function makes use of `ord` and `chr`, while performing a loop over each character in the input string `s`. We collect the reversed result of each character in the string into `res` and return that string.

```
>>> reverse('ab')
'zy'
```

You might be wondering where `- ord(char) + 219` part came from. Indeed, this is the core logic we use to reverse each character. This is nothing but some simple math. At the end of the day, our goal is to find some function `y = f(x)` where `x` is the input character (e.g. `'a'`) and `y` is the output character (e.g. `'z'`). Here are a few x-y coordinates for your reference:

```
x  --> y
97 --> 122 # ord('a') --> ord('z')
...
109 --> 110 # ord('m') --> ord('n')
110 --> 109 # ord('n') --> ord('m')
```

With some thinking, we can convince ourselves that this is a simple linear function `y = - x + 219`. This is what we're doing in the function.

---

**EDIT**: `reverse` cannot be used alone as it is if you want to reverse entire sentences. I'm assuming we don't have to reverse a space keys or any other white space.

```
def reverse_sentence(sent):
    words = sent.split()
    words = [reverse(word) for word in words]
    return ' '.join(words)
```

In action:

```
>>> reverse_sentence('this is an apple')
'gsrh rh zm zkkov'
```

Note that this implementation reverses each word only, not the order of the words themselves. If you want to reverse the order of the words, modify the last return statement as

```
    return ' '.join(words[::-1])
```

Lastly, a full disclaimer that this solution does not deal with capital letters of the alphabet. Capital letters have different `ord` values, which means that this approach has to be complicated to generalize further to capital letters. If capital letters do not matter, you can use `some_string.lower()` to first preprocess the input into lower case letters, then pass it into `reverse` or `reverse_sentence`.